# Can we fetch the results using one RowMapper object instead of creating objects everytime?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

When fetching results from database through `SpringJdbcTemplate, everywhere I have seen that they are passing the new object of` RowMapper` every time.

Is this required? Or can we just use one object and pass it again and again?

Example:

```
Student student = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[] { id }, new StudentRowMapper());
```

I know this object will be garbage collected later on, but I didn't wanted to create the same object over and over again.

Can I reuse the row mapper instance, like this?:

```
Student student = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[] { id }, this.studentMapper);
```

Has this any thread safety issue?

Comment: Of course you can, and it's proper way instead of creating new one every time for each iteration.

Comment: *Has this any thread safety issue?* it all depends on the code of StudentRowMapper. Note that this is an insignificant, premature optimization. Creating a Java object is several orders of magnitude faster than executing a SQL query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just create your `RowMapper` and let Spring manage it? There should be no reason to create a new instance every time. Just autowire in the one managed by Spring. As long as your mapper isn't doing anything non-thread-safe, then should be just fine.

```
@Component
private RowMapper class...
```

...

```
@Service
WhateverService class...

@Autowired
private SomeRowMapper theRowMapper;


public void doSomething() {
    Student student = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[] { id }, theRowMapper);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should be able to reuse the object.

As long as your class is thread safe there is no issue. JdbcTemplate is thread safe by design